# Disaggregate binned data to continous so that sums within bins are preserved

Tags: r

I have binned data for the number of deaths within six age groups:

```
data.frame(start=c(0,21,41,61,81,101),end=c(20,40,60,80,100,116),dead=c(11,63,275,981,1261,15))
  start end dead
1     0  20   11
2    21  40   63
3    41  60  275
4    61  80  981
5    81 100 1261
6   101 116   15
```

Is there a way to disaggregate the data so that it approximates the number of deaths for each single-year age but the sums of deaths within bins are preserved?

This method doesn't preserve the sums within bins, and the number of deaths is too low in ages 81-100 and too high in ages 101-116:

```
d=data.frame(start=c(0,21,41,61,81,101),end=c(20,40,60,80,100,116),dead=c(11,63,275,981,1261,15))

xy=do.call(rbind,apply(d,1,\(x)data.frame(x=seq(x[1],x[2]),y=x[3]/(x[2]-x[1]+1),row.names=NULL)))
xy$debin=predict(smooth.spline(xy,spar=.8),xy$x)$y

png("1.png",600,400)
plot(xy$x,xy$y,xlab="Age",ylab="Dead")
lines(xy$x,xy$debin,col="red")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this approach of iteratively fitting a LOESS curve:

```
d=data.frame(start=c(0,21,41,61,81,101))
d$end=c(20,40,60,80,100,116)
d$dead=c(11,63,275,981,1261,15)

xy=cbind(d[rep(1:nrow(d),d$end-d$start+1),],age=unlist(mapply(seq,d$start,d$end)))
xy$debin=xy$dead=xy$dead/(xy$end-xy$start+1)

for(i in 1:100){
  temp=predict(loess(debin~age,xy,span=.2))
  mult=tapply(xy$debin,xy$start,sum)/tapply(temp,xy$start,sum)
  xy$debin=temp*mult[as.character(xy$start)]
}

png("1.png",600,400)
plot(xy$age,xy$debin,type="l",col="red",xlab="Age",ylab="Dead",mgp=c(2,1,0))
points(xy$age,xy$dead)
dev.off()
```

The sums within bins are preserved:

```
> tapply(xy$debin,xy$start,sum)
  0   21   41   61   81  101 
 11   63  275  981 1261   15
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`sample` with replacement from within each age-range/row.
The `Map` call essentially does the looping by row by passing each of the vectors as an argument:

```
d <- data.frame(start = c(0,21,41,61,81,101),
                end   = c(20,40,60,80,100,116),
                dead  = c(11,63,275,981,1261,15))

## make reproducible by setting a seed
set.seed(1)
deaths <- unlist(Map(
    function(s,e,d) sample(seq(s, e), size=d, replace=TRUE),
    d$start, d$end, d$dead
))
table(cut(deaths, c(0,d$end), include.lowest=TRUE))
##   [0,20]   (20,40]   (40,60]   (60,80]  (80,100] (100,116] 
##       11        63       275       981      1261        15
barplot(table(deaths))
```

Comment: In my case I'm trying to basically fit a continuous curve to the data, so that for example there should be less deaths for age 41 than age 60.

Comment: @nisetama - that's going to be very hard/impossible to fit when the count falls off a cliff at the oldest age group. I'd be excluding that 100+ group to make anything fit well.